# web.GetList("Lists/TestList") throws FileNotFound exception

Tags: sharepoint-server, object-model, splist

I have the following code in my application. It is throwing

> FileNotFound exception at `web.GetList("Lists/TestList")

This list exists and I am able to get the list from `web.Lists.TryGetList("TestList")`. But I am getting exception when I am trying to get the list from the relative URL. Can anyone please help me?

```
            string siteUrl = "<siteURL>";

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.GetList("/Lists/TestList");
                }                   
            }
```

Comment: `GetList` requires the full url as far as I can remember

Comment: Nope, but a "ServerRelativeUrl"!

Comment: can you try this SPList lists = web.GetList("Advertisements");

Comment: yeah .. could be something like `list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SPList list = web.GetList("/Lists/TestList");
```

Should be

```
 SPList list = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/TestList");
```

As it needs the server relative URL to your list

Comment: Thanks Robert, Nadeem and Dave. That was really helpful. I should have checked MSDN properly before posting it. Really sorry for the inconvenience. But anyway, thank you very much to all of you, for helping me out quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use server relative Url of the list:
Example: The server-relative URL to the root folder of a list, such as `/sites/sitecollection/subsite/Lists/Announcements.`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `/Lists/TestList` is the right (relative) URL?

Try the `SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl` method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spurlutility.combineurl.aspx

Something like this:

```
List targetList = targetWeb.GetList(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(targetWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, "/_catalogs/yourList"));
```